# How can I implement efficient way to search prefix in set of fixed length arrays of bytes?

Tags: algorithm, search, go, arrays

I have a large set of fixed length arrays of bytes, something like e.g.:

```
type Fixed [64]byte

set := make([]Fixed, 10240)
```

Most of this entries have distinct 5-7 byte prefix.
How I can implement efficient way to find elements of `set` based on given prefix? e.g.:

```
set.Find([7]byte{ /*...*/ }) == /* no hit || single hit || multiple hit */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

You can store your set as a trie and given a prefix you go all the way down and get to a node. Then you just traverse the subtree rooted at this node to get all your items.

Answer (score 0):

As mention above trie can be good for you.
Also you can use hash table, the key will be the first 7-8 bytes (can use long for it), the access time is O(1) and I think is simpler to implement.

Comment: That is not an option for me, as it might happen that I'll need to search longer or shorter prefixes, and some may collide.

Comment: The value in the hash able will be all the work with this prefix.In case the key is less then 7 byte - just pad them with 0.